# React native exception: syntax error when running on iphone 7 plus

Tags: react-native

I am getting a syntax error when running my react native app on iOS 10.2 iPhone 7 Plus simulator and iPhone 7 Plus physical device but not on iPhone 7. I have to idea where to begin looking for problem.
[image: syntax error] 
Here is my package.json file.

```
{
  "name": "NativeProject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --progress --colors --hot --inline --host 0.0.0.0 --port 3000",
    "test": "jest",
    "build": "webpack -p"
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "fonts"
    ]
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-react-native",
    "globals": {
      "__DEV__": true
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.22.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-jest": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^1.9.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.5",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
    "express": "^4.14.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.10.0",
    "firebase": "^3.6.8",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "jest": "^18.0.0",
    "jest-react-native": "^18.0.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "moment": "^2.17.1",
    "postcss": "^5.2.11",
    "postcss-cssnext": "^2.9.0",
    "postcss-import": "^9.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^1.2.1",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-addons-css-transition-group": "^15.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.1",
    "react-native": "^0.41.1",
    "react-native-calendar": "^0.10.0",
    "react-native-calendar-picker": "^3.0.0",,
    "react-native-cli": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "^0.5.0",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^1.2.7",
    "react-native-sglistview": "^0.3.2",
    "react-native-swipeout": "git+https://github.com/magrinj/react-native-swipeout.git",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.0.0",
    "react-native-video": "1.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.2",
    "react-router": "^3.0.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "^15.4.1",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-logger": "^2.8.1",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.2.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "reselect": "^2.5.4",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0-rc.3"
  }
}
```